# Show that if $X= \emptyset$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$ then $r\emptyset=\emptyset+r=\emptyset$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if $X= \emptyset$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$ then $r\emptyset=\emptyset+r=\emptyset$.

Defitinions:

- $X+r=\{x+r:x\in X\}$,
- $rX=\{rx:x\in X\}$.

Can you hint me? I know I will use these defitions. Yet, how?

Comment: If $X = \emptyset$, there are no elements $x \in X$, and hence both of the sets are empty by definition.

Answer (score 3):

Vacuous truth is your friend. If $X=\varnothing$, can you find any $x\in X$?

(Another way of doing so is proving that in $\Bbb R$, $r+X$ and [when $r\neq 0$] $rX$ have the same cardinality as $X$. How many sets have the same cardinality as $\varnothing$?)

Comment: Correction: $rX$ has the same cardinality as $X$ if $r\neq 0$ (or if $r$ is not a left zero divisor when $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by an arbitrary ring).

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\{x+r:x\in X\}$ is a shorthand for
$$
\{y:\text{there exists $x\in X$ with $y=x+r$}\}
$$
(write the formula with logic symbols, if you prefer); equivalently, it denotes the image of the function $X\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $x\mapsto x+r$. Thus the set is empty if $X=\emptyset$.